# Is electric field emitted from a charged particle

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Is the Electric Field that, we say, exist around a charge, emitted from the charge.

For example, consider during a nuclear process, a new charge has been created. It's field will take some time to influence the charges nearby.

What should we interpret from it?